# Refrescar tabla datatables(jquery)

Tags: ajax, datatables

Estoy usando  esta instrucción `table.ajax.reload();` para refrescar una tabla de DaTables pero no funciona el refresco. No da ningún tipo de error.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado de esta forma:

```
$('#miTabla').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```